# Ambigous type variable in variable parameter (printf-like) function

Tags: haskell

I am writing an interpreter and I'd like to have a function that takes a function with normal parameters and converts it into a function that works with the interpreter. E.g.:

```
add :: Monad m => Int -> Int -> m Value
let myadd = convert add :: Monad m => [Value] -> m Value
```

I created some classes that actually make it happen as long as `m` is concrete - but I would need the result to still have type `m Value`, not e.g. `IO Value` (I need to use it in 2 different monads).

```
data Value = VInteger Int  deriving (Show)

class MyArg a where
  fromValue :: Value -> Maybe a

instance MyArg Int where
  fromValue (VInteger a) = Just a
  fromValue _ = Nothing

class Monad m => MyFunc m r where
  convert :: r -> [Value] -> m Value

instance Monad m => MyFunc m (m Value) where
  convert f [] = f
  convert _ _ = fail ""

instance (Monad m, MyArg a, MyFunc m r) => MyFunc m (a -> r) where
  convert f (arg:rest)
    | Just v <- fromValue arg = convert (f v) rest
  convert _ _ = fail ""
```

I have this function to convert:

```
testfunc1 :: Monad m => Int -> Int -> m Value
testfunc1 num num2 = return $ VInteger (num + 10 * num2)
```

And this works:

```
main = do
  let val = convert (testfunc1 :: Int -> Int -> Maybe Value) [VInteger 3, VInteger 5] :: Maybe Value
  print val
```

However, this doesn't:

```
let val = convert testfunc1 [VInteger 3, VInteger 5] :: Maybe Value
```

And this, which is my usecase, doesn't either:

```
funclist :: Monad m => [ [Value] -> m Value ]
funclist = [
    convert testfunc1
  ]
```

The error is:

```
No instance for (GHC.Base.Monad m1)
  arising from a use of ‘Main.testfunc1’
The type variable ‘m1’ is ambiguous
```

It seems to me that the typeclasses somehow fail to grasp that the `m` of the converted function should be the same `m` as in the original function, but I have no idea how to code it inside it.

Comment: The thing that makes this so tricky is that `(->) a` is a perfectly valid type for a `Monad`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is that the compiler can't assume there is no instance for `MyFunc m (a -> r)` such that `Int -> Int -> m1 Value` will fit for some `m1` different from `m`: someone could add it in a different module. This is called the open world assumption.

This should be easy to fix by

```
funclist = [
    convert (testfunc1 :: Int -> Int -> m Value)
  ]
```

(not sure off-hand if [`-XScopedTypeVariables`](https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/7.8.4/docs/html/users_guide/other-type-extensions.html#scoped-type-variables) is required; if it is, add `forall m.` to `funclist` signature).

Comment: I had to add ScopedTypeVariables, forall m. and Incoherent instances, because it somehow wants to apply both instances ('the choice depends on the instantiation of m'). Any idea why incoherent instances is required?

Comment: Interestingly enough in my real code the IncoherentInstances is not needed.

Comment: "Any idea why incoherent instances is required?" `m` could be `(->) a` and `r` could be `Value` in which case you have 2 instances for the same types.